# How can I mark a calendar item as complete but leave it on the calendar in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

How can I mark a calendar item as complete but leave it on the calendar in Outlook 2010?  For instance I have a lot of doctor appointments, its nice to know whether I went or not and also to look back & see when the last time I had a doctor appointment.  I have many doctors and would like to be able to look at my complete medical history.  How can I get this done?

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You might just want to delete the ones where you didn't go? Would you for some reason need to know how many appointments you had but cancelled?

If you need to keep this info I'd say the best way is to right click on the event & Categorize it. You can use different colors to mean different things & [Change the name of each color to help you keep track of them](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/change-appointment-and-meeting-color-labels-HP003084844.aspx)